# Python: how to avoid append an empty string in a for loop?

Tags: python

The goal of my codes are to write a function and return a list of strings, in which the successive strings (fruit name) correspond to the consecutive `#No.1...#No.5` . The whole name of the fruit was split over multiple lines, and I want to display the fruit name in the list as a single string with no whitespace.
I expect my codes return:

```
['Pear', 'Apple', 'Cherry', 'Banana', 'Peach']
```

but I got:

```
['', 'Pear', 'Apple', 'Cherry', 'Banana', 'Peach']
```

These are the contents of my file `fruit.txt`:

```
#NO.1
P
ear
#NO.2
A
pp
l
e
#NO.3
Cherry
#NO.4
Banan
a
#NO.5
Pea
c
h
```

These are my codes:

```
def read(filename): 

    myfile = open('fruit', 'r')
    seq = ''
    list1 = []
    for line in myfile:

        if line[0] != '#':
            seq +=line.rstrip('\n')
        else:

            list1.append(seq)
            seq = ''

    list1.append(seq)    
    return list1
```

how to avoid to append an empty string which is not what I want? I suppose I just need to adjust the position a certain line of codes, any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Please note that your function will result in a memory leak if called repeatedly. You should never open a file without making sure it is subsequently closed.

The easiest way to do this is by using the `with` construct.

For further reading, see this link: http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Comment: @sobek Got it, thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could change the

```
    else:
```

to

```
    elif seq:
```

This checks whether `seq` is empty and only appends it if it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix for removing empty strings from a list:

```
list1 = filter(None, list1)
```

How about this solution with [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)? The following is a two-step process. First all whitespace like newlines, spaces etc. is removed. Then all words following your pattern `#No.\d` are found:

```
import re

whitespace = re.compile(r'\s*')
fruitdef = re.compile(r'#NO\.\d(\w*)')
inputfile = open('fruit', 'r').read()

inputstring = re.sub(whitespace, '', inputfile)
fruits = re.findall(fruitdef, inputstring)

print fruits
```

> ['Pear', 'Apple', 'Cherry', 'Banana', 'Peach']

---

Minified to a oneliner:

```
import re

print re.findall(r'#NO\.\d(\w*)', re.sub(r'\s*', '', open('fruit', 'r').read()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative if you'd like a single line solution:

```
with open('fruit.txt') as f:
    content = f.read()

output = [''.join(x.split('\n')[1:len(x.split('\n'))+1]) for x in content.split('#') if len(x.split('\n')) > 1]
```

Comment: Good solution, Thank you!